# Can a telebot be able to send sms to its user?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to make a telegram not which at some point is like to send an SMS to the user or verify something through SMS but I'm not sure if the telegram API allows for that. If it is possible, please his can I utilize it?

Note:I'm just a beginner in python so some things might seem unclear to me so please be easy on me

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Telegram bot API has nothing to do with user phone numbers. Due to a variety of security reasons, it doesn't give bots access to such information and if we just suppose that, why should it send SMS? It's not the responsibility of a messenger like Telegram.

You can just send users notifications on Telegram or asks them for their numbers, then send SMS by another service.